# group list by condition to create list of lists

Tags: c#, list, group-by

I have a `List<type1> listOfObjects` and a `static` method

`bool CheckIfObjectsAreEquivalent(type1 obj1, type1 obj2)`.

I would like to *group* the list by the *equivalence criteria*, i.e. have `List<List<type1>> result` where *each list* consists of the objects that are *equivalent* according to `CheckIfObjectsAreEquivalent`.

Another important aspect is, that I do not know upfront how many different lists will result from this grouping, as all objects could be equivalent or none or any possible number of equivalence groups. The initial list of objects `listOfObjects` can consist of variously many objects and to see if two of those objects are equivalent one must use `CheckIfObjectsAreEquivalent`.

I've been looking into different options using `.Where` and `.GroupBy` but I can't get it to work...

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are no real attempts that someone could use to go from there. All my attempts stalled when trying to use the method that tells me if two objects are equivalent...sorry this isn't more help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `IEqualityComparer<type1>` interface and then use the implementation in `GroupBy`:

```
public sealed class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<type1> {
  public bool Equals(type1 x, type1 y) {
    // Your method here
    return MyClass.CheckIfObjectsAreEquivalent(x, y);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(type1 obj) {
    //TODO: you have to implement HashCode as well
    // return 0; is the WORST possible implementation
    // However the code will do for ANY type (type1)
    return 0; 
  }
}
```

Then you can put:

```
var result = listOfObjects
  .GroupBy(item => item, new MyEqualityComparer())
  .Select(chunk => chunk.ToList()) // Let's have List<List<type1>> 
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for this swift return! What does the GetHashCode getter do actually? Oh and would I have to insert the code of the `CheckIfObjectsAreEquivalent` method again in the `Equals` method of the `MyEqualityComparer`?

Comment: @user5971293: `GetHashCode` provides a hash code (which is the same for all equal items) for quicker comparison: if hash codes are different then items are different (no need to execute `Equals`)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. In may case, equality is given if 4 properties out of 5 match, where all 4 to be checked are of type `string`. How would I convert those into a meaningful integer for the getter?

Comment: @user5971293: something like this: `public int GetHashCode(type1 obj) {if (null == obj) return 0; return obj.Field1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Field2.GetHashCode(); }` where `Field1` and `Field2` the fields / properties you compare instances by.

Comment: @Dimitry: thanks that makes sense!! I'll try and see where I get to :)

Comment: @user5971293: be careful with `GetHashCode` it **must**: 1. Run on *any* `type1` instance (do not forget checking for `null`)  2. Return the *same* value for equal instances 3. Be *fast* (do not put *every* property but only few the most distinct and simple ones)

Comment: @Dimitry: is the GetHashCode of a string always identical to an identical string? Because that is what I would do, I would use the Hash Code of three properties and take them to the power. Every object of type1 has those properties...

Comment: @user5971293: `string` can be `null` and you can compare (i.e. treat as identical) strings in *different ways* (e.g. *case insensitive*). `obj.StringProperty?.ToUpperInvariant()?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;`

Comment: ok, I see. won't be a problem. The strings are taken from a data base and standardized. Case differences or such won't be possible. Thanks a lot!!!!